# ng-readonly not disabling date picker in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

The date picker plugin is still working even if the field is readonly.

`<input name="SpecialFields_{{::field.FieldID}}" ng-model="newUserObj.specialfields[field.FieldID]" type="text" class="DatePickerClass form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" datepicker-localdate is-open="popup.customDate[$index].opened" autocomplete="off" placeholder="e.g. 01-January-2000" datepicker-options="dateOptions" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" ng-required="field.RequiredField == 1" ng-readonly="field.AdminEditable && (isAdmin == 0)">`

Is there any way to disable the datepicker

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to use `ng-disabled="field.AdminEditable && (isAdmin == 0)` instead of `ng-readonly`.

This will prevent changes.

Comment: yes, that would be an option, but the problem with disabled fields is that it wont get posted on form submission. that's why i wanted to use readonly instead of disabled